# c -why it gives run time error but it gives output

Tags: c

here my program is running and it gives the output is 93, but it generates run time error i could not understand why it is?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int ,int );
int main()
{

 printf("addition is=%d \n",add(91,2));
}
int add(int a,int b)
{
return (a+b);
}
```

OUTPUT
Runtime error
addition is=93

Answer (score 4):

In C89, you need to return an `int` from `main`. For example,

```
int main(void)
{
 printf("addition is=%d \n",add(91,2));
 return 0;
}
```

Where a return value of `0` signifies success. Compiling your code in C89 mode with gcc 4.9 would yield the following warning:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

In C99 or C11, an exception is made for the `main` function, where there is an implicit `return 0` in the absence of a return statement. So your code would have no errors in standards newer than C89.

Comment: So the reported "Runtime error" is only the shell's interpretation of the (undefined) returned value?

Comment: Since C99, `main` is an exception to this (there's an implicit `return 0;` at the end), see 5.1.2.2.3; [this C89 draft](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) reads (2.1.2.2 "Program termination") _If the main function executes a return that specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host environment is undefined._

Comment: @mafso Thanks for the info. So C99 is like C++ in this respect, and in C89 the behaviour is not undefined, but the returned status is (presumably it is a valid, but indeterminate value.)

Comment: If something is wrong with this answer I'd be interesting in knowing so I can think about improving it.

Answer (score 1):

can you notice the two functions that you are using in your program.

```
int main()
int add()
```

both have return type as `int` (integer). But you are returning `(a+b)` from add() but not returning anything from the main()..

try `return 0` at the end of the main() function.

there are a number of options that you can choose from while returning from main function. this will help you pass information to the C runtime about how the programm has executed. for example, `return 0` is for normal execution, and `return 1` is for error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of main() to "void "or else put "return 0; " in main function. You specified main function of return type int but the function does not returns anything hence the error occurs and output shows since int add(int , int) is returning (a+b) correctly.

Comment: `main` should really return `int`.

Comment: @juanchopanza not necessary. You can specify return type of main to void in C. I had done it before.

Comment: It is required in a hosted environment, i.e. something with an OS. It is in the C standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza Is that to signal the OS.